# Why VM in domain can't see SQL Server outside domain?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, sql-server, windows-domain, odbc

I have the following scenario:

- 1 Windows 10 home host machine with SQL Server up 2017 and running.
- 1 Domain server VM running over host machine.
- 1 Windows 10 pro VM running over host machine, and joined to domain.

They are all in the same subnet and they can ping each other but trying to connect from Win 10 Pro VM to SQL Server instance in host machine fails (using ODBC and SQL Server login and password). It says:

```
Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server Version 17.02.0000

Running connectivity tests...

Attempting connection
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.

TESTS FAILED!
```

I have even turned off firewall on both host and guest but yet ODBC fails to connect. It used to work before, the only difference I can tell is that, for some other reasons, I had to re-join Win 10 Pro VM to the domain and purged all non-domain users other than the VM local administrator.

Besides, I'm not sure how it showed before, but now it says this VM is connected to Domain Network (as opposed to a Private Network which is where SQL server resides). Could that be an issue?

Comment: What does SQL Server log says when you attempt to connect? (remember to check if the *login auditing* under the server properties is configured to log failed logins)

Comment: Thank you @Ronaldo, I was preparing to see logs when it came to my mind that I had not tried to connect from local administrator's session in VM (using ODBC DSN). I did it and it worked. Then I tried from domain user session where I originally found the problem, and it worked! So I can't even place this as an answer to my own question as I'm not certain what is that resolved it in the first place. I had already restarted VM's like 3 times each and have done nothing else besides login in as local admin and try.